# Creating multiple descriptive tables (with a loop) and storing as dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, iteration

I am trying to create a simple 'for loop' to produce a series of descriptive tables (saved as dataframes) using R but am struggling to do so.

For example, I can create a simple descriptive table (called 'Var_1_tab') like so:

```
library(janitor)

Var_1<- c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b")
Var_2<- c("b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "a")
Var_3<- c("c", "b", "a", "c", "c", "b", "a")

df<- data.frame(Var_1, Var_2, Var_3)

Var_1_tab<- df %>% janitor::tabyl(Var_1)
```

I want to use a loop to sequence along each column in my dataframe and produce the same simple descriptive table for each column, storing the result in my global environment as a dataframe. Added bonus would be to be able to name each dataframe as 'Var_1_tab', 'Var_2_tab' etc, for ease of reference.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabyl` can take quoted column names as well.  So, we loop over the column names and save the output in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df_lst <- map(names(df), ~ df %>% 
      janitor::tabyl(all_of(.x)))
names(df_lst) <- paste0(names(df), "_tab")
```

-output

```
> df_lst
$Var_1_tab
 Var_1 n   percent
     a 2 0.2857143
     b 5 0.7142857

$Var_2_tab
 Var_2 n   percent
     a 4 0.5714286
     b 3 0.4285714

$Var_3_tab
 Var_3 n   percent
     a 2 0.2857143
     b 2 0.2857143
     c 3 0.4285714
```

The list elements can be extracted with `$` or `[[` using the names

```
> df_lst[["Var_1_tab"]]
 Var_1 n   percent
     a 2 0.2857143
     b 5 0.7142857
```

If we need to create objects in the global env (not recommended), use `list2env` on the named `list`

```
list2env(df_lst, .GlobalEnv)
```

and check for the objects

```
> Var_1_tab
 Var_1 n   percent
     a 2 0.2857143
     b 5 0.7142857
> Var_2_tab
 Var_2 n   percent
     a 4 0.5714286
     b 3 0.4285714
```

Comment: Just for my learning, can I ask why it’s not recommended to create objects in global environment?

Comment: @C.Nugent because list is very easy to manipulate i.e. suppose you wanted to apply some function on all the elements.  It can be done by looping with `lapply/map` etc.  If those are objects in the global env, then have to identify those objects get its values and then apply. Also, it is easier to write back to files